# How to generate points along a line at specific locations AND not at an equidistant intervall in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, linear-referencing

Is there an option to generate points along a line at a specific location only? Say, when I want a point at 5% of the total length of the line and 95%. When using `Generate Points along line` I can specify the `point placement as percentage` and assign it to 5 respectively 95, but I just want a single point and not an intervall of points.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use arcpy, the most flexible way to place points (or segments) on polylines is the use of "linear referencing". You first need to create M-aware geometries and update their values, but once this is done it becomes very easy to locate your points along your routes.

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/linear-referencing/what-is-linear-referencing.htm

Comment: thanks @radouxju! i thought of that workflow, unfortunately I don't have those points beforehands i want to generate them straight from the specification of their percentual location along the line. Thats not straigtforward via linear referencing, is it?

Comment: if you set your start M at zero and your end M at 100, then you can populate a route event table in percent.